# Trying to move a button further down the page

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to web development so I apologize if this is a "newbie" question, I've looked on various sites and tried various things but am not able to move a button on my page to where I want it to go.

Here's the code I have for it in HTML:

```
 <div class="crown">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/8/d/6/12205466202120645650portablejim_Chess_tile_-_King_1.svg.med.png" height="250" width="200">
             <h3><strong>Join today!</strong></h3>
              <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-two" href="#">Register</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>


    <section class="footer">
      <div class="container">
          <p>&copy; 2016</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

And here's the CSS for it:

```
.btn-two {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin: 20px 0 -30px 0;}
```

I've tried a lot of things in the CSS that aren't working. I want the button to be a few inches below the "Join today!" text but it stays where it's at, like a hair below the text when I want there to be space in between the text and the button. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? And again I'm new to all this so I appreciate your understanding. Thank you.

Comment: without the `a` element being displayed as block, the margin and padding won't typically render. You could dry setting `display: inline-block` in your css, or alternatively put the padding/margin on the `p` element that is the parent to the button.

Comment: before your <a   you could add some breaks  <br /> to line break, it would quickly add some space for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `display:inline-block;` or `block` to the `.btn-two` since anchor elements are `display:inlin`e by default and `margin/padding` can't affect em

Check the snippet below

```css
.btn-two {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
I am fairly new to web development so I apologize if this is a "newbie" question, I've looked on various sites and tried various things but am not able to move a button on my page to where I want it to go. Here's the code I have for it in HTML:

<div class="crown">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/8/d/6/12205466202120645650portablejim_Chess_tile_-_King_1.svg.med.png" height="250" width="200">
    <h3><strong>Join today!</strong></h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-two" href="#">Register</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<section class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>&copy; 2016</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove `text-align:center;` style from the `<p>` that contains the button.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L210zqvf/

Answer (score 0):

Apply `display: inline-block;` to your `.btn-two`. An `<a>` tag is an inline element, generally not accepting width, height, margins etc. as long you don't do the above.

Yeah, and if you don't want it to be centered, remove `style="text-align: center;"` from your `<p>` Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor `a` elements are `display:inline` by default in a browser. Inline level elements can't have margin or padding, top or bottom. You can only apply margin and padding to the left or right of an element.

In your case. I'd put a class on the containing paragraph element and add margin to the top of that. Paragraph elements are block level elements.